# How to access the elements of a column of a matrix using a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, vector

I have a matrix `A` and I need to pass a pointer to a `function` to access the elements of a given column, here is a part of the code, where `PtrColumn` should be a pointer to the vector representing the column `j` of `A`. Is there a way to get this pointer without calculating the transpose of the matrix `A`.

```
    vector<vector<double>> A;
    int l=4,c=5;
    A.reserve(l)
    for(size_t i=0;i<l;++i)
    {
    vector<double> row;
    row.reserve(c)
     for(size_t j=0;j<c;++j)
        row.puch_back(j);
    A.puch_back(row);
    }
////// some part of the code/////
    for(size_t j=0;j<c;++j)
      function(PtrColumn) //PtrColumn is a pointer to a vector, and my vector is the column j of A
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a matrix class and a wrapper class for the columns:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Matrix;

class Column {
    Matrix *A;
    std::size_t column;
    
public:
    Column(Matrix &A, std::size_t column);
    double &operator[](std::size_t row);
    std::size_t size() const;
};

class Matrix {
    std::size_t columns;
    std::size_t rows;
    std::vector<double> A;
    
public:
    Matrix(std::size_t l, std::size_t r) : columns(r), rows(l), A(l * r) {}
    double &operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) { return A[i * columns + j]; }
    std::size_t getColumns() const { return columns; }
    std::size_t getRows() const { return rows; }
    Column getColumn(std::size_t column) { return Column(*this, column); }
};

Column::Column(Matrix &A, std::size_t column) : A(&A), column(column) {}
double &Column::operator[](std::size_t row) { return (*A)(row, column); }
std::size_t Column::size() const { return A->getRows(); }

void function(Column col) {
    std::cout << col[2] << '\n';
    std::cout << col.size() << '\n';
}

int main() {
    int l = 4, c = 5;
    Matrix A(l, c);
    for(size_t i=0;i<l;++i)
        for(size_t j=0;j<c;++j)
            A(i, j) = j;

////// some part of the code/////
    for(size_t j = 0; j < c; ++j)
      function(A.getColumn(j)); //PtrColumn is a pointer to a vector, and my vector is the column j of A
}
```

Here is a code without matrix class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Column {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> *A;
    std::size_t column;
    
public:
    Column(std::vector<std::vector<double>> &A, std::size_t column) : A(&A), column(column) {}
    double &operator[](std::size_t row) { return (*A)[row][column]; }
    std::size_t size() const { return A->size(); }
};

void function(Column col) {
    std::cout << col[2] << '\n';
    std::cout << col.size() << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> A;
    int l=4,c=5;
    A.reserve(l);
    for(size_t i=0;i<l;++i) {
        std::vector<double> row;
        row.reserve(c);
        for(size_t j=0;j<c;++j)
            row.push_back(j);
        A.push_back(row);
    }
////// some part of the code/////
    for(size_t j=0;j<c;++j)
      function(Column(A, j)); //PtrColumn is a pointer to a vector, and my vector is the column j of A
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: storing A as as a reference in the `Column` class makes it unassignable and moveable. It's much more convenient to store a pointer internally. Of course the external interface would stay the same, so that you're forced to construct a `Column` from a "matrix" that actually exists (i.e. no `nullptr`s).

Comment: @Darhuuk I changed it.

Comment: thank you fr your answer, but I really need that my matrix A be of type vector<vector<double>> and not the class Matrix that you defined because I used many predefined function of std::vector in my code

Comment: @user108724 I added a second version.

Comment: thank you for the update, with the operator [ ] I can access to the elements of the column, but `function` receives a parameter of type double * and `col` is an object of type `Column` and I cannot find any why to get from `col` a pointer `double *`

Comment: @user108724 You can't. If you can't change the signature of the function you have to copy the elements into a new array.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot change `function`, so I think that it would be better if I transpose the matrix `A` since at each iteration of the `for` loop, I need the pointer of a column